# Обмен местами элементов линейного списка С

Tags: c, list, указатели

Задача заключается в том, чтобы поменять первый и последний элементы списка местами. Не могу понять, почему первый элемент переносится в конец списка, а последний в начало не переносится.
На тесте "1 2 3 4 5" программа выводит "2 3 4 5 1". Как переместить пятерку в начало линейного списка?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct list
{
   int el;
   list *next;
};

int main()
{
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   list *L, *r, *p = new list;
   L = r = p = new list;
   p = p->next = new list;

   // Ввод списка
   FILE *str;
   fopen_s(&str, "C:\\Users\\forev\\Desktop\\tx.txt", "r");
   int a = 0;
   while (0 < fscanf_s(str, "%d", &a))
   {
      r->next = new list;
      r = r->next;
      r->el = a;
   }
   r->next = NULL;
   fclose(str);

   // Обработка
   for (r = L->next; r->next != NULL;)
      r = r->next;
   p = r->next;
   r->next = L->next;
   p = L->next->next;
   L->next = p;
   r->next->next = NULL;


   // Вывод списка
   r = L;
   printf("Измененный список: ");
   for (r = r->next; r; r = r->next )
      printf("%d ", r->el);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас первый элемент списка пустой, что не очень хорошо.
2. Изначальный указатель списка всегда должен указывать на первый элемент.
3. Для облегчения понимания кода, со списками работают с помощью вспомогательных функций. И код ниже не является образцовым.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct list
{
    int el;
    list *next;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    list* current;
    list* first;
    list* previous;

    list * r = new list;
    r->el = 0;
    r->next = NULL;

    // Ввод списка
    FILE *str;
    fopen_s(&str, "C:\\Users\\forev\\Desktop\\tx.txt", "r");
    int a = 0;

    int first_read = 1;
    current = r;
    while (0 < fscanf_s(str, "%d", &a))
    {
        if (first_read) {
            r->el = a;
            r->next = NULL;
            first_read = 0;
            current = r;
        }
        else {
            current->next = new list;
            current = current->next;
            current->el = a;
            current->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    fclose(str);

    printf("Считанный список: ");
    for (current = r; current; current = current->next )
        printf("%d ", current->el);
    printf("\n");

    // Обработка
    previous = current = r;
    while (current->next != NULL) {
        previous = current;
        current = current->next;
    }
    first = current;
    first->next = r->next;
    r->next = NULL;
    previous->next = r;
    r = first;

    // Вывод списка
    printf("Измененный список: ");
    for (current = r; current; current = current->next )
        printf("%d ", current->el);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```